# UIStackView floating view

Tags: uiscrollview, ios9, uistackview

I guess there will be more people looking for this, but it's nowhere to be found.

What I want is to make one or more subviews of the UIStackView float once the scrollview that contains the UIStackView gets scrolled past the top of the view(s). The behavior should be similar to tableview headers.

Answer (score 0):

I will tell you my first thought about it.

Try to detect the scrolling using a delegate from `UIScrollViewDelegate` like this

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    }
```

check the current Y of the scroll view like this:

```
scrollView.contentOffset.y
```

make your condition, and if true, change the position of the UIStackView.

But I wouldn't recommend such a solution. Maybe it is better to check the UI best practices and stick with a *header of the table view*

Answer (score -1):

@Rebel Designer, have you heard the **ScrollableStackView** library? Here is the github page :

https://github.com/gurhub/ScrollableStackView

And some sample codes for you :

**Swift**

```
import ScrollableStackView

var scrollable = ScrollableStackView(frame: view.frame)
view.addSubview(scrollable)

// add your views with 
let rectangle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 55))
rectangle.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
scrollable.stackView.addArrangedSubview(rectangle)
// ...
```

**Objective-C**

```
@import ScrollableStackView

ScrollableStackView *scrollable = [[ScrollableStackView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
scrollable.stackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionFillProportionally;
scrollable.stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignmentCenter;
scrollable.stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical;
[self.view addSubview:scrollable];

UIView *rectangle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 55)];
[rectangle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

// add your views with
[scrollable.stackView addArrangedSubview:rectangle]; 
// ...
```

Hope it helps.